# Woocommerce add to cart button redirect to its summary page (single.php)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to redirect the user when click on add to cart it redirect to specific product single page (summary page).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this hook to redirect after add to cart (woocommerce)

```
function cdx_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
    $page_id = 213;  //Page ID or product ID where you want to redirect after add to cart
    $url = get_permalink( $page_id ); 
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'cdx_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```